# Rails find method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get an id from the record.

When i write this:

```
@ticket.table = Table.find(:all, :conditions => {:train => @ticket.train, :datestart => @ticket.selldate})
```

I suppose it returns amount of the records.

Help me please.

UPD:
I have an output:

```
=> [#<Table id: 6, train: 1, time: "12-00", datestart: "2012-01-10", created_at:
 "2012-01-10 01:59:29", updated_at: "2012-01-10 01:59:29">]
```

Table id is 6. I need to get it.

Comment: You have to include (1) the output you're getting, and (2) the output you expect. You're not including any output - how are we to know what's going wrong? For this particular issue we also need to see the model definition for the `Table` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` is just a property on that object. Simply call:

```
 > @ticket.table.id
=> 6
```

Assuming that the `Table` class is a sub-class of `ActiveRecord::Base`, all objects of this type should have an `id` attribute that you can just reference with `.id`

The problem you're having above is that you're using `.find(:all, ...)` which will **always** return a collection of objects, even if only one record is found, which is what's causing you to get an array with only one element in it.

Therefore, either use `.find(:first, ...)` or `.find(:all, ..., :limit => 1)`, to return just one row, or simply reference the first element in the array via one of the following methods:

```
 > @ticket.table.first.id
=> 6
```

or

```
 > @ticket.table[0].id
=> 6
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But it says that there is no method id in such array(!!!). I've already tried that method.

Comment: Oh! I missed that it was an array the first time I read it. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
@ticket.table = Table.find(:all, :conditions => {:train => @ticket.train, :datestart => @ticket.selldate}).map(&:id)
```

will give you array of ids for all your satisfying condition. If you want only one id use the code below.

```
@ticket.table = Table.find(:all, :conditions => {:train => @ticket.train, :datestart => @ticket.selldate}).map(&:id).first
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is better for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Instead of map you can use collect method I have seen pros use collect though both of do same thing.